# Jquery slider: smooth click animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

jquery sliders contain a "animate" opton that when set to "true" will slide the handle into postion when the slider bar is clicked.

Im using my slider to scroll the content in another div, creating a similar eeffect as the one on the apple website. http://www.apple.com/mac/

the problem is that when i click the sliderbar it smoothly animates the handle but not the other div. i have the other div scrolling on the "slide" and "change" events. any ideas how i can achieve smooth scrolling for the other div?

Thanks in advance, oh gods of jQuery.

my code:

```
var list = $('.sliderGallery ul');

$('.slider').slider({
    min:0,
    max:1500,
    animate: true,
    slide: function(event, ui) { list.css('left', '-' + ui.value + 'px'); },
    change: function(event, ui) { list.css('left', '-' + ui.value + 'px'); }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I used JavaScript but as far as I remember jQuery you can try to do the same thing you are already doing but using animation effect. Try this:

```
var list = $('.sliderGallery ul');

$('.slider').slider({
    min:0,
    max:1500,
    animate: true,
    slide: function(event, ui) { list.animate({'left': '-' + ui.value + 'px'}, 'normal'); },
    change: function(event, ui) { list.animate({'left': '-' + ui.value + 'px'}, 'normal'); }
});
```

This code may not work right away but it hopefully might serve as a starting point. Here's a link to this function documentation: [animate( params, [duration], [easing], [callback] ) in Effects/animate](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/animate#paramsdurationeasingcallback).

Comment: Hey Ped! I can look at it more and hopefully come up with a working solution, but I seriously lack testing environment. Would you mind adding to your question a simple implementation of the thing you're trying to achieve that will have the same problem of not being smooth enough. It'll be much easier ( and not for me only, I'm sure) to help you if helping you wouldn't require additional efforts to build a sandbox.